# JPOX JDO and Castor JDO compared to Hibernate persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, jdo, castor-jdo

Do these frameworks (JPOX JDO and Cater JDO) work off similar principles as Hibernate?
Do they use configuration data plus a combination of reflection and generics? What are some of the major architectural differences?

Comment: I guess one thing that I can see from doing some research is that JDO seems to used a byte code enhancement. Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Castor JDO is not "JDO" (Java Data Objects). It still performs persistence but not to any "standard" so is misleading in naming and they know it. JPOX implements JDO and JPA standards for persistence. DataNucleus replaced JPOX some time ago and is the persistence solution adopted by Google AppEngine. DataNucleus allows JDO/JPA annotations/XML and support generics. Hibernate is an implementation of JPA

--Andy ([DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org))